# Need Help updating chart data in flutter at every x amount of seconds

Tags: flutter

So I'm using the Sparkline library for flutter to create a line chart and it works when I use a static list Eg. ([0, 10, 20, 20, 30]). But I want to make it so that at every say 10 seconds it would add a value, for now that could be anything but later i want to pull that value from firebase.

I've looked at other examples of people trying to run a function multiple time init state but it isnt working. I know I need to redraw the widget but I don't think I'm doing it right or I'm missing something.

```
class BikeState extends State<BikeScreen> {
  Timer timer;
  List<double> speedList = new List();
  Sparkline speedChart1 = Sparkline(data: [0],);


void updateChart(Timer timer){
  speedChart1 = Sparkline(data: speedList,);
  speedList.add(10);
  speedChart1 = Sparkline(data: speedList,);
}

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 15), updateChart);
}


@override
void dispose() {
  timer?.cancel();
  super.dispose();
}
```

All that happens when i run it is that I get the just the graph which has the values passed into it when it was declared and nothing was changed.

Comment: You need to call `setState` in `updateChart` so that the framework knows that the state has changed and it should schedule a repaint.

Comment: I tried that but it still wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter will not repaint or rebuild any widgets for you on its own. In your case you already have a stateful widget, which is the correct way, but you also need to tell flutter that your state has changed. This is done by using the `setState` method like this:

```dart
void updateChart(Timer timer) {
  setState(() {
    speedChart1 = Sparkline(data: speedList,);
    speedList.add(10);
    speedChart1 = Sparkline(data: speedList,);
  });
}
```

Additionally, depending on how your `build` method looks, I think you should remove the Sparkline Widget from your state and have it purely during build like this:

```dart
class BikeState extends State<BikeScreen> {
  Timer timer;
  List<double> speedList = new List();


  void updateChart(Timer timer){
    setState(() {
      speedList.add(10);
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 15), updateChart);
  }

  @override
  void dipose() {
    timer?.dipose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Sparkline(data: speedList);
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of void build do you mean widget build?

Comment: I tried the code and it only works for the first 15 seconds and then from there it doesn't update. Is there anything i can try to fix that?

Comment: what do you mean by not updating? If you always push the value `10` the appearance of the sparkline will not change, so maybe try to push random data and see what happens.

Comment: So i've tried to push both the value 10 and 20 to the graph like so

` speedList.add(20); speedList.add(10);`

but it only works for the first 15 seconds. It only then shows the updated graph after I hot reload it.